# jq producing duplicates when I updated/replaced the value in array

Tags: json, shell, jq

Here are the input JSON files:

**input.json**

```
[
   {
      "Id":"123456"
   },
   {
      "Id":"7890123"
   }
]
```

**array.json**

```
[
   {
      "DataId":"{{ID}}"
   },
   {
      "DataId":"{{ID}}"
   }
]
```

I try to replace placeholders in array JSON with IDs from the input file and create new array of objects.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
cat input.json | jq '.[] as $inputs |[ $endFile[] + {"DataId": $inputs[]}] ' --argjson endFile "$(<array.json)"
```

I am getting the duplicates and I have no clue, why:

```
    [
      {
        "DataId": "123456"
      },
      {
        "DataId": "123456"
      }
    ]
    [
      {
        "DataId": "7890123"
      },
      {
        "DataId": "7890123"
      }
    ]
```

I need to have the same structure as the array.json only with values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for simplicity, e.g.:

```
 jq -n '
 (input| map(.Id)) as $ids
 | input
 | reduce range(0; length) as $i (.;
    .[$i].DataId = $ids[$i] )
' input.json array.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real `array.json` has other fields in the objects besides the `DataId` one that you want to pass through unchanged (I added one)...

```sh
$ jq -n '[ inputs ] | transpose | map(.[0] + {DataId: .[1].Id})' array.json input.json
[
  {
    "DataId": "123456"
  },
  {
    "DataId": "7890123",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]
```

---

This works by creating an array of arrays of objects, each sub-array holding the corresponding objects from the two input arrays, and then iterating it and for each sub-array, constructing an object with all the fields of the first object (From `array.json`) but the value of `Id` from the second object for the `DataId` field.